# pfSense : How to do 1:1 NAT to server hosted at remote location linked through IPSec tunnel

Tags: firewall, nat, ipsec, pfsense

We have 2 data centers at 2 different locations and are moving our services from location A to B without interruption.  Both location have a PFSense Firewall configured with IPSec tunnel between each other and everything is working fine.  I am able to ping LAN machines at location A from location B LAN and vice versa.  I have an FTP server at location A using a public WAN address from location A using 1:1 NAT and is working fine.   What i need is to setup a WAN IP address at location B that will be able to access the same server through the IPSec tunnel at location A for me to slowly move the IPs in DNS of multiple domains to location B's new IP to eventually shutdown location A and finally move the server to a LAN IP at location B.

**Network Schematic**

[image: Network Schematic]

When i go to the DIAGNOSTIC / PING menu at location B and try to ping the server at location A, it works fine if i select the LAN as source address but does not work if i use DEFAULT or any other address.   Of course if i setup a 1:1 at location B from the WAN to the LAN IP of the server at location A, it does not work.

Yes I did setup a rule in IPSec to allow ANY ANY from all.

Any idear of where i should look?  outbound NAT, custom ROUTES?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you figure it out? Looking to do the same...

Comment: Not yet ! Still waiting for an answer and looking for solution !   If you did please share !